# Unity android will build but can not run on device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build the Google VR Demo for Unity.  I have installed the command line tools which includes the sdk but when I click build and run it can not find the android device even though I have the USB turned on in the developer settings.  it will build an APK but will not run.

Comment: Since only Build is working but Build and Run is not, do you get any error from Unity console?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have USB debugging enabled on the phone. Just go to settings developer options and enable ADB or USB Debugging. If the problem persists, a workaround for this is to just copy over the APK to the device, install it and just run it from the phone.